# How to split an UInt() into a Vec of UInt to do subword extraction and assignment?

Tags: chisel

I have a 16bits register declared like that :

```scala
val counterReg = RegInit(0.U(16.W))
```

And I want to do indexed dibit assignment on module output like that :

```scala
//..
  val io = IO(new Bundle {
     val dibit = Output(UInt(2.W))
  })
//..
var indexReg = RegInit(0.U(4.W))
//..
io.dibit = vectorizedCounter(indexReg)
```

But I have some difficulties to know how to declare `vectorizedCounter()`.

I found some examples using Bundles, but for Vector I don't know. And I can't manage to do that with UInt():

```scala
val counterReg = RegInit(UInt(16.W))
//...
io.dibit := counterReg(indexReg*2.U + 1.U, indexReg*2.U)
```

Comment: `io.dibit := ` ?

Comment: exact, corrected (but it was not the problem ;)

Comment: Is `vectorizedCounter` a `UInt`?

Comment: Yes it is. I updated the question to add the type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could dynamically shift and bit extract the result:

```scala
io.dibit := (counterReg >> indexReg)(1, 0)
```

Comment: I am doing similar but in my case, the widths may not be proper multiple, hence, the width I take may wraparound, so some bits are from one end and remaining after wraparound. I am having to use a UInt as index, which is not allowed, how may I handle that ? My question is @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67650528/how-to-dynamically-index-into-a-register-using-another-register-in-chisel/67653227#67653227. Thanks