# How to dynamically index into a register using another register in Chisel

Tags: scala, queue, fifo, chisel

I am writing Chisel code for what I am told to be a type of funnel shifter.
Basically it gets inputs of size m bits and sends outputs of size n bits where m and n can have any relationship or not.

I am saving the m bit words in a buffer and then need to dynamically index into the buffer to get n bits. Similarly for writing, I must write at the boundary of n rather than m to not have a sort of fragmentation. For this I am using read_pointer and write_pointer registers.and need to select bits from the buffer using the pointers as indices.

But Chisel is not allowing me to use a register as an index value into another register. How can I do this ?  THe code is as -

```
   when (io.pull && !(io.empty))
   {
       when ((buffer_rp +& out_word_size.U) <= (buffer_size-1).U ) // No wraparound
       {
           io.data_out := buffer (buffer_rp + (out_word_size - 1).U, buffer_rp)
       }
       .otherwise // Wraparound
       {
        
       }
   }
```

The error message I get is -

cmd24.sc:87: overloaded method value apply with alternatives:
(x: BigInt,y: BigInt)chisel3.UInt 
(x: Int,y: Int)chisel3.UInt
cannot be applied to (chisel3.UInt, chisel3.UInt)
io.data_out := buffer (buffer_rp + (out_word_size - 1).U, buffer_rp)
^Compilation Failed

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Jack Koening](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2483329/jack-koenig) gave me a [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59001903/4422957) for similar question [some years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58995390/how-to-split-an-uint-into-a-vec-of-uint-to-do-subword-extraction-and-assignmen).

You could dynamically shift and bit extract the result:

```scala
           io.data_out := (buffer >> buffer_rp)(out_word_size - 1, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks the above solution worked to read from buffer without wraparound. I have two more cases that I need to work. I also need to handle wraparound, some bits on/from one end of the buffer and remaining bits on/from the other end. Also, I need to dynamically write to the buffer at different locations. Do you know what is the right way to handle these ? Thanks